# MVVM loses command binding

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have an unusual problem with my view model. I have a list of the items and I need to to have a button with attached command to each item. I'm using ItemsSource and each item is represented with this view model:

```
public class CarItemViewModel : ViewModelBase, ICarItemViewModel
    {
        public void Init(Car definition, Action<Car> onSelection)
        {
            Wehicle = definition;

            SelectCarCommand = new RelayCommand(() => onSelection(definition));
        }

        public Car Wehicle { get; private set; }

        public ICommand SelectCarCommand { get; private set; }
    }
```

Then in my ViewModel for page I'm calling method below to populate list in OnNavigatedTo or Loaded event:

```
public void ShowCars()
        {
            var newCar = new Car()
            {
                Make = "Mazda",
                Model = "MX-5"
            };

            var carVM = new CarItemViewModel();
            carVM.Init(newCar, SelectCar);
            Cars.Add(carVM);
        }
```

Binding for data is working fine. I can see names etc but button with bound command is sometimes inactive and it won't hit a break point in SelectCar method. When I do a little trick and before calling ShowCars() I add Task.Delay(200) it will be fine.

I'm developing for Windows Phone 8 Silverlight and using newest MVVM Light. Anyone got similar issue?